# Area between curves: how to tell if $f(x)$ is above or below $g(x)$?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Let's say I want to find an area between some functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

What is the best way to find out if I should use

$$\int_{a}^{b} [f(x)-g(x)]dx$$

or

$$\int_{a}^{b} [g(x)-f(x)]dx$$

That is, what is the best way to find out if $f(x)$ lies above or below the function $g(x)$ on the interval $(a,b)$?

So far I have been graphing the function and I could tell that quite easily. But it takes some time and feels like it's very "crafty" way.

Also, the $a$ and $b$ values I am either finding while graphing the functions or by solving $f(x) = g(x)$.

I am mostly dealing with trivial functions, nothing too complicated.

Comment: You basically also have to solve $f(x) >g(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ don't intersect each other inside the interval $(a,b)$, then you can simply pick any value $c$ inside the interval $(a,b)$ and see if $f(c)$ is bigger than $g(c)$ or the other way around. If $f(c) > g(c)$ then $f(x)$ will be greater than $g(x)$ on the entire interval. This only assumes both functions are continuous and relies on the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem), which I suppose is a reasonable assumption judging from the question.

Answer (score 3):

The correct expression is: $$\int_{a}^{b}{\left|f(x)-g(x)\right|}dx$$

> E.g Let’s find the area between $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=x+2$ for $x\in[-3,3]$.

Note that $f(x)-g(x)=x^2-x-2$ which has two roots $2$ and $-1$ and in $[-3,-1]\cup[2,3], f(x)-g(x)\ge 0$.

We split therefore $\int_{-3}^{5}{\left|f(x)-g(x)\right|}dx$ into $\int_{-3}^{-1}{•}+\int_{-1}^{2}{•}+\int_{2}^{3}{•}$.

More precisely:

> $$Area=\int_{-3}^{3}{\left|x^2-x-2\right|}dx=\int_{-3}^{-1}{(x^2-x-2)}dx+\int_{-1}^{2}{(-x^2+x+2)dx}+\int_{2}^{3}{(x^2-x-2)dx}$$

Comment: To actually compute it using primitives we do need to know which one to take, we might have to split the interval into parts..